# How to add new authorization header to Apollo client within a React component?

Tags: reactjs, authorization, apollo, next.js, apollo-client

How can I add a token to an Apollo client authorization header within a react component?

I have a login function which passes a Google authorization code to the backend, receives an encrypted token and I want to add this to the authorization header so every request made after this contains it and can be validated on the backend to protect the API routes.

This token is returned to a React component, but I am not sure what command to use to do this? I assume client.writeData is meant for local storage but not in the context of headers.

Here's the code I have in my React component:

```
export default function LoginForm() {
    function userLogin(code){
         let token = googleAuthenticate(code.code);
         if(token === Error()){
            console.log("poop");
         }else{
            // ADD NEW AUTHORIZATION HEADER HERE.
         }
    }

    return(<div>
             <GoogleLogin
            clientId="xyz"
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={userLogin}
            onFailure={userLogin}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
            hostedDomain={"blabla.com"}
            responseType={"code"}

  />
            </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use localStorage() like this:

```
function userLogin(code){
   let token = googleAuthenticate(code.code);
   if(token === Error()){
     console.log("poop");
   } else {
     localStorage.setItem('token', token);
   }
}
```

Then modifying the ApolloClient code accordingly:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  request: (operation) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    operator.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

You'll have to write some code for when you logout to wipe the token, etc.,

This can be found on the [ApolloGraphQL.com](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication/) site too.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Since I am using an SSR website I am unable to use localstorage. Will the second code portion you showed make the modification of the header to the client? The impression I got it wouldn't do anything because you just instantiate a variable with that functionality but it isn't actually applied. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Instead of localStorage you could use indexeddb? Here's a tutorial link to help with that if you choose to do so: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb

Comment: I will check this out, thank you friend. Although, it wouldn't be necessary if I could set the header from that react component. I suppose it is not possible?

Comment: This header should only be set after a certain function has been called anyways. So setting the header in the client initialization is not the objective, but rather it be triggered after I receive the token from the backend. This token is transferred to this component. So I don't think any local storage is necessary.

Comment: SSR always makes things harder. Take a gander at the [official example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo-auth) for how to set up your client.

Comment: save cookies in localstorage is not safe.  i don't recommend this method.